# how to write this SQL statement Update Where in?

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Update [E1$] 
set [LR/Virtual/MW]='LR' ,  
[Vir No#]=null  
where [Conc] , [Vir No#]
  in   (    
    SELECT  [Conc] , [Vir No#]
    FROM [E1$]  
    where [Vir No#] is not null 
    group by Conc , [Vir No#] 
    having  Count(LR)<28
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    Update E set [LR/Virtual/MW]='LR' , [Vir No#]=null  
  from [E1$] E join
       (SELECT  [Conc] , [Vir No#]
        FROM [E1$] where [Vir No#] is not null 
        group by Conc ,[Vir No#] 
        having  Count(LR)<28
       ) a
 on e.[Conc]=a.[Conc] 
    and e.[Vir No#]=a.[Vir No#]
```

Comment: I receive an exception >
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'null  from [E1$] E join (SELECT  [Conc] , [Vir No#] FROM [E1$] where [Vir No#] is not null group by Conc ,[Vir No#] having  Count(LR)<28) a on e.[Conc]=a.[Conc] and e.[Vir No#]=a.[Vir No#]'.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)

Comment: @AhmedDarwish: Are you getting the error in sql sever or in front end application?

Comment: front end... when i run it in the SQL management studio it runs correctly

Comment: @AhmedDarwish: So its not the problem with the query. I dont know much about .Net, create a stored procedure with this query and try to run the procedure from front end.. that might help..

Answer (score 0):

Try using parenthesis around `([conc], [Vir No#])` in the `where` clause.

```
Update [E1$] 
set [LR/Virtual/MW]='LR' ,  
[Vir No#]=null  
where ([Conc] , [Vir No#]) in
(    
   SELECT  [Conc] , [Vir No#]
   FROM [E1$]  
   where [Vir No#] is not null 
   group by Conc , [Vir No#] 
   having  Count(LR)<28
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update [E1$] 
set [LR/Virtual/MW]='LR',[Vir No#]=null  
where exists(    
    SELECT  [Conc] , [Vir No#]
    FROM [E1$] e2 
    where [Vir No#] is not null and  [E1$].[Conc]=e2.[Conc] and [E1$].[Vir No#]=e2.[Vir No#]
    group by Conc , [Vir No#] 
    having  Count(LR)<28
)
```